# substract two date with in seperate column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
awbno       byhub        entrydatetime           uplopadtime
 111            ho       2017-01-01 10:10:13.000    2017-01-01 10:10:13.000
 222            ho       2017-01-01 18:10:13.00     2017-01-02 10:10:13.000
 333            ho       2017-01-01 13:10:13.000    2017-01-03 10:10:13.000
 444            ho       2017-01-01 10:10:13.000    2017-01-05 10:10:13.000
```

I would like to output like this way by substracting entrydatetime from uploadingdatetime:

```
byhub   total_awbno   sameday     oneday    twoday    morethan_two_day
 ho         4           1           1          1          1
```

I used this Query  but not found right solution:-

```
select byhub , 
       COUNT(awbno),    
       count(case when (datediff(day,uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)=0) then 1 end ),    
       count(case when (datediff(day,uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)=1) then 1 end ),    
       count(case when (datediff(day,uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)=2) then 1 end ),    
       count(case when (datediff(day, uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)>2) then 1 end )    
from MyTable  
group by byhub
```

The output of my query is:

```
ho 4 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT byhub,
       COUNT(awbno) AS total_awbno,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN days_diff = 0 THEN 1 END) AS sameday,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN days_diff = 1 THEN 1 END) AS oneday,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN days_diff = 2 THEN 1 END) AS twoday,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN days_diff > 2 THEN 1 END) AS morethan_two_day
FROM (
   SELECT awbno, byhub, datediff(uplopadtime,EntryDateTime) AS days_diff
   FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY byhub;
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/QKRLA6413)

Answer (score 1):

`datediff()` function in MySQL has only 2 parameters: 2 date values. The function you are looking for is [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and you also need to reverse the order of the fields in the parameter list if you would like to substract entrydatetime from uploadingdatetime:

> TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)
>
> Returns datetime_expr2 − datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and
>   datetime_expr2 are date or datetime expressions. One expression may be
>   a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a datetime
>   having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary. The unit for the
>   result (an integer) is given by the unit argument. The legal values
>   for unit are the same as those listed in the description of the
>   TIMESTAMPADD() function.

```
select byhub , 
       COUNT(awbno),    
       count(case when timestampdiff(day,EntryDateTime,uplopadtime)=0 then 1 end ),    
       count(case when timestampdiff(day,EntryDateTime,uplopadtime)=1 then 1 end ),    
       count(case when timestampdiff(day,EntryDateTime,uplopadtime)=) then 1 end ),    
       count(case when timestampdiff(day,EntryDateTime,uplopadtime)>2 then 1 end )    
from MyTable  
group by byhub
```

`timestampdiff(day,EntryDateTime,uplopadtime)` is the same as `datediff(EntryDateTime,uplopadtime)`

Answer (score -1):

Check Bellow

```
  select byhub , 
       COUNT(awbno),    
       sum(case when (datediff(uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)=0) then 1 else 0 end ),    
       sum(case when (datediff(uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)=1 or datediff(uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)=-1) then 1 else 0 end ),    
       sum(case when (datediff(uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)=2 or datediff(uplopadtime,EntryDateTime)=-2) then 1 else 0 end ),    
       sum(case when (datediff(uplopadtime,EntryDateTime) > 2 or datediff(uplopadtime,EntryDateTime) < -2) then 1 else 0 end )    
from MyTable  
group by byhub
```

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice. How is an asker supposed to learn from his questions and their answers, if the answer is just a piece of code with no explanation? Thus, the only skill he improves is his copy&paste-skill.